# use remote repository withEgit

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket

I am trying to use a project from a repository on bitbucket that someone else created, but when i try to import it and place it in my C:\Users---\git folder, I can't run it from my localhost obviously.

Then when I try to import the repository to my htdocs folder (localhost) and try to import the project it gives me the error:

> A ressource exists on disk with different case: ("path to imported
>   project on localhost")
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.ressource.RessourceException

I don't get it, as I had no problems when I created my own project and shared it on my bitbucket repo.

So how do I import this project in eclipse and still be able to test on localhost and also commit/push/pull to the remote repository?

EDIT: I can create the git clone of the repository, but I can't run it on localhost.. can it moved or linked to my htdocs folder somehow?

Comment: Can't you clone it directly in the right folder (ie your `htdocs` folder)

Comment: nope, if I do that it gives me an error.